# Parse c++ and extract all used types and functions

Tags: c++, parsing, types, minify, lexer

I want to write a program that runs before Visual Studio compiles my project.
It needs to extract only the types, names and parameters of all functions, classes, structs, enums my project is using from files in a specific folder (/sdk) and copy those into a new folder (/sdkmin)

So I basically want to have a program that minifies the sdk my project is using.

Is there any decent library that allows me to do that without having to write my own parser/lexer/whatever?

Comment: Well, sounds like you're trying to write your own, special-purpose, C++ compiler; or at least its parsing phase. That should take, oh, maybe 5-10 years for one person to do.

Comment: How about look into the symbol table *after* you compile the program with the full "sdk"? That would give you a list, but extracting such list from the original source is non-trivial task.

Comment: Maybe ctags, definitely libclang.

Comment: Try asking at "Software Recommendations".  SO is going to close your question, because they claim it isn't about programming.  Nonsense.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you should do is look at some clang tools like "clang-format", "include-what-you-use", etc., which build on the clang AST front-end stuff to do various interesting things. This will provide the lexer and parser for you, which would indeed take a very long time if you started from scratch.

Github mirror here: https://github.com/llvm-mirror/clang